# Switches from any press to tweak

Tags: modeling

[image]

After any click on a field or a cube just anywhere I am redirected to the "tweak" tab.
What can I do to stop being thrown to this tab?

Comment: Maybe somehow related to the answer in this post? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/313951/rotation-keyboard-shortcut-has-stopped-working-properly-how-to-fix/313956?noredirect=1#comment544090_313956